# Application deployment failed in websphere 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, ear

org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NoModuleFileException:A file does not exist for module element having uri

Comment: I'd recommend you explain a bit more about what you are doing, the environment, and additional details so we can help you. 

BTW, WebSphere 7 is out of support as of April of this year. Have you considered upgrading to version 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your application.xml contains one or more module elements.  The error message is telling you that a module you have defined in application.xml is not found in your application.  That is, the file is not in your .EAR file.

Suppose your application.xml contains these elements:

```
<module>
    <java>MyClient.jar</java>
</module>

<module>
    <ejb>MyEjb.jar</ejb>
</module>

<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>MyWar.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>mywar</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

Then your .EAR file should contain these files in the root directory:

```
MyClient.jar
MyEjb.jar
MyWar.war
```